# How to create a function that converts a set of strings to integer

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, integer

I have been struggling for a couple of days now before turning here.

I'm trying to build a function, StringToInteger, that converts a textstring to integer. I have researched the web and gotten so far that I have some code that convert one string, entered in a variable, to an integer.

```
DECLARE @YourString   varchar(500)
SELECT @YourString='select'

;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Number
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Number+1
    FROM AllNumbers
    WHERE Number<LEN(@YourString)
)
SELECT
   (SELECT
        RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(varchar(max),ASCII(SUBSTRING(@YourString,Number,1))),3)
        FROM AllNumbers
        ORDER BY Number
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.','varchar(max)') AS NewValue

 --OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500) --<<needed if you have a string longer than 100
```

I also found some code on how to query a table, TableB, and send its result to a function and have the whole set run.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
TableB
CROSS APPLY
dbo.StringToInteger(TableB.ColumnWithText) AS IntegerOutOfText
```

My question is, how should the code at the top be adjusted so that it is loaded into the db as a function when run? How much I try, I cant get SQL Server import it as a function.

And my other question is, how should the bottom code be adjusted so that it calls the function and have it convert the whole query's result set to a set numbers number.

Best regards 
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function could look like this:

```
create function StringToInteger(@YourString varchar(500))
returns varchar(1500) as
begin

  declare @Ret varchar(1500);

  WITH AllNumbers AS
  (
  SELECT 1 AS Number
          UNION ALL
          SELECT Number+1
      FROM AllNumbers
      WHERE Number<LEN(@YourString)
  )
  SELECT @Ret =
     (SELECT
          RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(varchar(max),ASCII(SUBSTRING(@YourString,Number,1))),3)
          FROM AllNumbers
          ORDER BY Number
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
     ).value('.','varchar(max)');

  return @Ret;
end
```

Use like this:

```
DECLARE @YourString   varchar(500)
SELECT @YourString='select'

select dbo.StringToInteger(@YourString)
```

Use with a table like this:

```
declare @T table (Col1 varchar(10))
insert into @T values('select')

select dbo.StringToInteger(Col1)
from @T
```

Comment: It returns a value but not in datatype integer, which is what I need. I tried to change the variables in the function bigint (also int) but ran into: Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The conversion of the varchar value '050051051049' overflowed an int column.

Comment: Also get: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.

Comment: @user Here you can see the max sizes for int and bigint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: Is there a better way to solve the problem of getting creating a numeric id instead of a string id? An approach that doesn't involve ascii and hence doesn't generate so large numbers?

Comment: @user I'm sure there is. You should post that as a new question. If you think this question is answered you should accept the answer with the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have some substring to parse out before you do the conversion?

what about `TO_NUMBER()`?  that seems alot simpler.

Comment: Hmm,I google it a bit. It seems to only an Oracle command. What I want to do is take a string like: 'Hello World' and get an integer number. Tried Mikaels answer. It returned an integer value but unfortunately not in the data type integer.